# Atlassian SDK 404 Error when trying to do atlas-run

Tags: http-status-code-404, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I followed the tutorial on

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/create-a-confluence-hello-world-macro/

But when I try to do atlas-run and open localhost:1990/confluence, I get a 404-error.

I already checked my java and sdk version multiple times.
Atlas 6.3.10
Apache Maven 3.2.1
Java jdk.1.8.0_191
Running on win10 home.

Another strange behaviour, all atlas commands won't refer to the changed working directory. All files were created in .../Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.3.10 and in the first lines it says "can't find path"

Any suggestions what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it.
Check solution on https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/atlas-run-in-tutorial-causes-404-error/24612